# Where can I find project risk management data?

Tags: data-request, business

Where can I find project risk management data, including assignment risks and historical occurrences of identified risk managing projects?

Comment: If anyone had it, I would assume it would be [PMI](http://www.pmi.org/).  But they would likely charge for it.

Answer (score 3):

Some *project risk management data* can be found within the following **resources**:

- [Enterprise Risk Management Initiative's Surveys and Benchmarking Data](http://erm.ncsu.edu/library/categories/category/erm-surveys-and-benchmarking-data) (free)
- [TM Forum's Business Benchmarking Database](http://www.tmforum.org/BusinessBenchmarking/10227/home.html) (commercial)
- [International Software Benchmarking Standards Group (ISBSG) Data Portal](http://www.isbsg.org/ISBSGnew.nsf/webpages/45E810BF882519148825799E00030EC7?open) or, alternatively, [ISBSG Industry Data Sets](http://www.isbsg.org/isbsgnew.nsf/webpages/~GBL~Industry%20Data) (commercial; *industry focus*: software / IT project data)

**NOTES:** 1) I don't think that Project Management Institute (PMP) has project risk management data, as @Joe suggested. At least, I haven't been able to find it. 2) Obviously, there exists other industry-focused project risk management data, similar to the one referenced above, focused on the software / IT industry.